# Dynamically size UIStackView when one of its items gets larger

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have two items in a vertical `UIStackView`: a `UILabel` and a `UITableView`. When a dynamic amount of `UITableViewCell`s get added to the `UITableView` at runtime, the `UIStackView` does not get larger.

Is there a general way to increase the size of the `UIStackView`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should call `sizeToFit()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` on the subviews of the stackView. Constrain the UIStackView as you normally would, and constrain the subviews as you normally would.

Also, you need to have it set to Fill Proportionally and it will resize to fit the new content.

Comment: Call them at instantiation or each time the `UITableView` is updated?

Comment: Try calling them in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubviews is a method in the UIViewController, so I don't understand the answer: "You should call sizeToFit() and layoutIfNeeded() inside viewWillLayoutSubviews on the subviews of the stackView."

Comment: Thanks! For those interested also in better understanding distribution and alignment, check out this article: https://medium.com/better-programming/uistackview-distribution-vs-alignment-146b9612e24c

Comment: if I to add spacing either with the `spacing` property or with constraints between elements, my last element in the stack view start to be resized, ignoring the height constraint

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you don't have a bottom constraint of a height constraint on the stackview. You should only need left, right and top constraint.

Comment: A `UIStackView`with with or without constraints does not seem to dynamically increase unless you add another element to it.

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal >= also didn't work for me. But removing the bottom constraint did.

Comment: I tried to use `=` but with lower priority (like 500) and it start to auto-layout a cell better

Answer (score 12):

I had this on iOS 12, while it was working fine on iOS 13.
Just set:

```
stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
```

Fixed it :)

Answer (score 5):

you one need to fill proportionally and it will work according to your code

Answer (score 0):

A bit old the question, but it might help others nevertheless.
I was looking a long time to get this right.
If you have a vertical stack view in which your subviews are placed, create an outlet of before mentioned vertical stack view and do the following in `viewDidLoad()` (of the popover view controller in my case):

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.preferredContentSize.height = verticalStackView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero).height
```

Unlike what @Siriss said, `sizeToFit()` was not necessary in my case.